# Rails: Executing Limited Includes and Complex Grouping w/ Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, group-by

Here's my basic model hierarchy:

```
Movie has many Listings and many Links through Listings
Listing has many Links
Link has a price (float)
```

I'm trying to fetch all movies that have Links with price = 0.00.

I do this easily with scopes:

```
scope :free, lambda{ 
     joins(:links).where('links.price = ?', 0.00)
     .group('movies.id')
}
```

This is all well and good in providing me a list of Movies that have free links, but when I go through and actually look at `Movie.links` it gives me all the links, not just the free ones.  This is problem one.

Problem two is that I need to pre-fetch several relations of Movie efficiently when I grab a list of them in the db.  To do this I use `includes()` as follows:

```
default_scope includes( 
    :formats, 
    :critic_ratings => [
        :network
    ], 
    :covers => [
        :network
    ], 
    :listings => [
        :links, :network
    ]
)
```

This works as well, but it's incompatible with the prior free scope.  That's to say that it will grab all of the attributes of the Movie, not just the free ones, and I don't know how to stipulate any limits to an item in a complex nest include statement like this one.  I'd like to be able to pre-fetch only the links `where('price = ?', 0.00)`.  The way I have it worked now, I grab all of the listings and links using this `default_scope` and then run a seperate `.free` scope I've established for Listings from within one of my partials rendering the page.  But when I do this, the query goes back to the db, which I'd assume is much slower than if I just manually filtered the pre-fetched results in-memory with my own trivial checks.

In summation:

Problem One: Properly groups or set up my scope so that Movie.links will only provide me with free links without forcing me to go back to db (i.e. I know I could do Movie.links.free w/ free being a scope defined for Link, but that would go back to db as far as I'm aware).  If there is no built-in solution for Problem One using scopes and grouping, I can just implement a helper to do the late-stage sorting in-memory to solve this, though it will provide some headache for complicated cases.

Problem Two: I want my scope to pre-fetch only a select set of Listings, Links, etc based on conditions I stipulate.  If we can't solve Problem One there probably is no solution to Problem Two, as there's no way for me to know which links have been pre-fetched and I'll have to scan them all over again to find the free ones unless Movie.links only gives me the free ones (would Movie.where() go back to db?).

Hopefully this isn't too confusing.  Thanks for any help.